# apt install php7.1-curl depends libcurl3 but I have libcurl4 installed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, php

There does seem to be some other related questions to this issue but I want to ask my own to give it more content specific to my situation, if it helps diagnose the problem and how to correct it.

I have multiple versions of PHP installed:
`sudo update-alternatives --config php` lists:

```
  0            /usr/bin/php7.3   73        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/php5.6   56        manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/php7.1   71        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/php7.2   72        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/php7.3   73        manual mode
```

I am trying to use PHP 7.1 for a project, and I need to get curl installed. The problem is that it keeps failing install due to dependency issues.

I can't install libcurl3 because it isn't available (and it probably isn't wise to do so considering libcurl4 is already installed).

```
libcurl4 is already the newest version (7.64.0-1).
```

I have tried different PHP versions and tried installing the curl extension for each, as well as `php-curl` (generally) as well. To no avail.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using PureOs Green. The solution to my problem was to update my sources (e.g. `sudo apt edit-sources`) for `ondrey/php` to:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic main
```

Where my `bionic` was `xenial` before.

I was then able to `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` followed by the library I was after, e.g. `sudo apt install php-curl`